# What is the Asterisk program event in Windows?

Tags: windows, system-sounds

What is the Asterisk program event in Windows?

[image: Sound and Audio Device Properties dialog box (mmsys.cpl) with Asterisk program event highlighted in red]

Comment: So much legacy.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7YiwTpQdT8 :]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the sound/event that is associated with the Windows *Information* alert type (vs. a *Critical*, an *Exclamation*, or a *Question*).

We can demonstrate this by creating a quick VBS script to create a new message box (see the [`MsgBox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)  function) and set its **MsgBoxStyle** to include the *Information* flag -  `vbInformation` = 64.

So create a text file named `info.vbs` or alike, and put this in it:

```vb
x = MsgBox("Here's some info", vbOKOnly Or vbInformation, "Information Dialogue")
```

Save it, and run it with `wscript info.vbs` or `cscript info.vbs`.

It will pop up a box with an OK button and the "information" icon, and also play the accompanying sound event ("Asterisk").

To compare, if you change the flag to something else, like `vbCritical` (= 16), which will display the matching "critical" icon, and play the "Critical Stop" sound.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Techie007's answer, an **information message box** is also called an **asterisk** because that's what its [stock icon was in Windows 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLlYc.png) and 2!

For the same reason, an **error** box used to be called a **hand**.

Source: [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20221108-36/?p=107367)